# When waking up from significant location change notification how much time do I have in the background?

Tags: ios, core-location

Testing an app that monitors a region then wakes up to do some processing. I cant seem to find anywhere documentation that says how long I have to do work in the background before the watchdog timer kicks in and kills the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a document (even I believe official one) where most of the timings related to background was shown. However, I can't find it right now (I will try to find it and post here).

Based on my experience, I believe application is awoken for 10 seconds while significant location change. Also, the interesting thing that if you try to do call backgroundTimeRemaining it will return +INFINITY for these 10 seconds (generally speaking this API is designed only for beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)

**Update 1**

Sorry. I wasn't able to find that document. I have a feeling that it was remove/updated by Apple, because before (about 6 month ago) I hit it quite often while searching information on iOS backgrounding.

I found couple of interesting things. One is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's related to VOIP callback.

It says: "Your handler has a maximum of 10 seconds to perform any needed tasks and exit. If it does not exit before time expires, the application is suspended."

Also, the same 10 seconds are mentioned [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) for Bluetooth:

"Upon being woken up, the app has around 10 seconds to process the data."

I believe underlying mechanics for location manager wake up, VOIP and Bluetooth wake up are exactly the same and all of them grant 10 seconds of execution time/

Comment: I think you are right about the 10 seconds, if you can find the doc, the bounty is yours.

Answer (score -1):

you can register for a maximum of 10 minutes background-task. 
But if you want to know, how long the called method can be executed, try measuring it with a infinite while-loop!